# Possible HDD failure soon?

Tags: hard-drive

4 days ago, I decided to download HD Tune just to see how my hard drive was doing. When I checked the program today I saw this...

[image]

When I first checked I had ~8300 Retry Counts and in 4 days it has increased by more than 1,000. This hard drive is in a 2010 Samsung R530 Laptop.

Should I be worried? I have already got backups of my data.

Comment: Has HD Tune been thrashing your hard drive for 4 days? If it keeps that up I'll bet it will fail soon... Or does it just report the drive's own smart results? I'm not familiar with it. Though it looks like it thinks your temperature is over 227 million degrees...

Comment: It does report the SMART data. Regarding the temperature being that high number, clicking on it displays the correct temperature in the Description

Comment: Hmm, ok. Data column must just be there for fun, or the "raw" value the drive keeps then

Comment: I just checked Hard Disk Sentinel and the values are the same as HD Tune in terms of raw data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't leave my only copy of irreplaceable data on the drive, but I wouldn't worry until I started to see more reallocated sectors & started getting read errors. Then drives can start "clicking" or pausing like they're "frozen" for a few seconds, those are big red flags that a drive's about to fail.

You can also check the drive's "smart" tests, if your programs can't do that then the HD manufacturer should have a program that can.

(Sometimes they can unexpectedly fail out of the blue too, so backups of important data are always a good idea)

Comment: I'll keep a check out for those signs. SMART Tests have all passed.